# Infinite Recursion C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I am writing this code that one function calls itself recursively. But I am stuck in an infinite loop because it seems when the function returns it doesn't return to the end bracket of the while loop but it returns to where int o is define.. any idea where the problem could be?

```
ErrorCode QuadTree::PartialSearchHelper(Key *key, const uint64_t QInternal, Iterator ** records,int l[], int pow) {
    try {
        uint64_t temp=(&indexVec[QInternal])->Firstchild;
        uint64_t ch = (&indexVec[QInternal])->Firstchild;
        for (int i = 0; i < pow; i++) {
            while (!(&indexVec[temp + l[i]])->isLeaf) {
                int o= l[i]; //it returns here after finishing recursion call!!!!!!!!!
                PartialSearchHelper(key, temp + l[i], records, l, pow);
            }                        
            ((&indexVec[temp + l[i]]))->findPartial(key, records);
        }

    } catch (std::bad_alloc &e) {
        throw (kErrorOutOfMemory);
    } catch (ErrorCode &e) {
        throw (e);
    } catch (...) {
        throw (kErrorGenericFailure);
    }
    return kOk;
}
```

Comment: At some point, this may cause a stack overflow.

Comment: "but it returns to where int o is define.. " oh no it doesn't.

Comment: Why do `(&indexVec[temp+l[i]])->`, when you can just do `indexVec[temp+l[i]].`?

Comment: If your while condition is still true, *of course* it will "return" there (i.e. wrap around and stay in the while loop). That is not the cause of your problem, semantics of your code are. Have you triple-checked your while-loop condition?

Comment: thnks but I tired inserting a break point at while condition but seems it doesn't even passes by!!!!!!!1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not changing any value inside the while, so it just restarts the while, in the lower level call

Answer (score 2):

Each recursive function call returns exactly to where it is called. Since you're in a while loop, you evidently continue with the next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the while loop there is no counter, there isn't any value changing. for instance, let's take a very basic example:

```
int i = 0;
while(i<5) 
{
  do.Something();
}
```

At this point, "i" will always be less than 5, so it will never stop. In the other hand, if you change it to something like this:

```
int i = 0;
while(i<5)
{
  do.Something();
  i=i++
}
```

The i value would increase by one every time it ran. If the while loop is inside a for loop, the while loop needs to be entirely done to loop back to the for loop. Try to use a for loop inside a for loop or insert some kind of counter in the while loop.

Comment: Seriously, `i = i++`? Never mind the missing semicolon, have you thought about what happens when you assign and post-increment the same variable?